# DataTable RowFilter is unchecking checkboxes in CheckedListBox

Tags: vb.net, search, textbox, checkedlistbox

I have a search function set up on a textbox. When text is typed into the box, the checkedlistbox visible items are filtered. When you check one of the visible boxes, then erase the search text, the checked item loses its check. Is there any way around this?

Search box:

```
Private Sub txtSearchBidder_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearchBidder.TextChanged
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtSearchBidder.Text) Then
        dtBidder.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Bidders LIKE '%" & txtSearchBidder.Text & "%'"
    End If
End Sub
```

CheckedListBox:

```
Dim dtBidder as new DataTable
dtBidder.Columns.Add("Bidders")
For Each bidder As String In cmd1.Parameters("@Bidders").Value.ToString().Split(",")
    dtBidder.Rows.Add(bidder)
Next
Dim source1 As New BindingSource()
source1.DataSource = dtBidder

chkListBidders.BindingContext = New BindingContext()
chkListBidders.DataSource = source1
chkListBidders.DisplayMember = "Bidders"
chkListBidders.ValueMember = "Bidders"
```

Comment: The CheckedListBox doesn't support data binding (which is why it tries to hide it).  You would have to keep a separate list of checked items and reapply them to the list after filtering them.

Comment: You should not be setting the `RowFilter` of the `DefaultView`.  You have a `BindingSource` so use it.  Set it's `Filter` property.  Also, add the `BindingSource` in the designer, not in code.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, there's nothing in the control or the binding that will do this for you, so you need to do it yourself, e.g.

```
Dim checkedItems = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast(Of DataRowView)().ToArray()

'Perform filtering here.

For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, checkedItems.Contains(DirectCast(CheckedListBox1.Items(i), DataRowView)))
Next
```